# Simplify if case that checks same value multiple times

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have a Wordpress function that checks so that two terms exists and creates them if they don't then sends it to another function to create post.

The problem is that the code gets very messy but it looks something like this

```
$arg1 = get_term_by('name', $term1, $taxonomy1);  //Checks so term1 exists
$arg2 = get_term_by('name', $term2, $taxonomy2);  //Checks so term2 exists

if ($arg1 == false && $arg2 == false){
    //creates term1
    //Creates term2
    //Passes on to create post
} elseif ($arg1 == false) {
    //Creates term1
    //Passes on to create post
} elseif ($arg2 == false) {
    //Creates term2
    //Passes on to create post
}
```

The biggest issue is that the two terms are assigned to two different taxonomies so I can't call another function to create terms without passing taxonomies and creating index with values for the taxonomies

Any idea how to simplify this if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check in advance if the term exists. Wordpress does it for you when you try to create a new one. You can do something like that:

```
$term1 = wp_insert_term(....) //create your term. If exists WP returns an error object
$term2 = wp_insert_term(....)

if ( !is_wp_error($term1) || !is_wp_error($term2) ) {
    // create your post
}
```

Comment: This worked great, reduced the function from about 70 lines to 20!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do a huge amount with it, but this reduces the amount of repeated code...

```
if ($arg1 == false) {
    //Creates term1
} 
if ($arg2 == false) {
    //Creates term2
}
if ($arg1 == false || $arg2 == false){
    //Passes on to create post
}
```

Comment: Going to post the same.